# google apps script two columns summary

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with two columns corresponding to lessons: the first with names of the porfessors (occasionally repeating themselves) and the second with numbers (number of hours). I would like to have as output two columns, the first with the names of the porfessors and the second with the sum of all the hours

I tried with the following code, but it seems to give me back two arrays with the initial colums, as if the condition  if (names[names.length-1] == namesColumn[i]) is never met.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
function resumeProfessors() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var namesColumn = sheet.getRange("C4:C31").getValues();
  var lessonsColumn = sheet.getRange("G4:G31").getValues();
  var names = [];
  names.length = 0;
  var lessons = [];
  lessons.length = 0;
  namesColumn.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < namesColumn.length; i++) {
    if (names[names.length-1] == namesColumn[i]){
    lessons[lessons.length-1] = lessons[lessons.length-1] + lessonsColumn[i];}
    else{
      sheet.getRange(i+4, 9).setValue(names[names.length-1] + namesColumn[i]);
      names[names.length] = namesColumn[i];
      lessons[lessons.length] = lessonsColumn[i];
    };}
writeResume(names, lessons);
}
```

Ty

Comment: Add more details about your spreadsheet. It could be useful if you create a demo spreadsheet share it with anyone with the link and include the link in your question. For further details see [mcve]. By the other hand, did you know that you can do the same by using built-in functions and features?

Comment: Agree with Ruben, Please create a sample spreadsheet and script if possible

Answer (score 0):

Given your use-case, I'd recommend using a Pivot table or the `=QUERY` formula.

However, assuming your **input sheet** looks something like this -

[image: input-sheet]

And the **expected output** is something like this -

[image: output-sheet]

You can try the below code -

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var output = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var inputValues = input.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(inputValues)
  for (var i = 1; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    var name = inputValues[i][0];
    var totalHours = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < inputValues.length; j++) {
      var hours = inputValues[j][1];
      if (name == inputValues[j][0]) {
        totalHours.push(inputValues[j][1]);
      }
    }
    var outputValues = output.getDataRange().getValues();
    var newEntry = true;
    for (var k = 0; k < outputValues.length; k++) {
      if (name == outputValues[k][0]) {
        newEntry = false;
      }
    }
    if (newEntry) {
      output.appendRow([name,totalHours.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b})]);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.